# Add buttons of the navigation of the rc-slider - react

Tags: reactjs, react-component, rc-slider

I'm trying to do this slider in react with rc-slider.
But I couldn't add buttons '-' and '+' on the marks.

I trying to do with marks, but marks doesn't accept the value the props.

My values for min={} and max={} are dynamics, then the value for - and + should be equal **minValue(min)** and **maxValue(max)**.

Here is my code, but the marks doesn't work.

```
<Slider
      min={minValue}
      max={maxValue}
      step={simulationType === 'type' ? 100 : 5000}
      onChange={this.props.onChange}
      defaultValue={this.props.value}
      marks={{minValue:'-', maxValue: '+'}} 
    />
```

[image]

Comment: Do you want 2 buttons to increase and decrease the slider's values?

Comment: yes, I need that 2 buttons to pass the values equal values on the step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you've got the use of `marks` wrong. They're used to just add indication about a particular value. I don't think they're meant to be interactive like the way you seem to want. You can add 2 buttons to do the job for you. And hook it up with the slider.

I've implemented it like this:

```
function SliderWrapper({ max, min, step }) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(min);
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => setValue(Math.max(0, value - 10))}>-</button>
      <Slider
        onChange={value => setValue(value)}
        value={value}
        step={step}
        min={min}
        max={max}
      />
      <button onClick={() => setValue(Math.min(100, value + 10))}>+</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

You can see the implementation in action here: https://codesandbox.io/s/1y1lzvxm6l. I've used [`useState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) React hook, but you could implement it as a class component with `state` if required.

Comment: Thanks for your help Maaz.
How can I use props on this component?
I'm trying convert in class components but doesn't work.

Comment: Which component are you referring to?

Comment: If you're talking about `SliderWrapper`, then you can just add more keys in the in the first function parameter.